# Is there a reason why code formatting does not have any rules?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, code, formatting

When I have a time, I really like to help people on Stack Overflow.

Questions I'm reading are mostly created by new users or others that did not ask much questions in a past. Those questions are sometimes fairly easy, but unfortunately, the code there is poorly formatted what makes them hard to read and also demotivates me from reading it or looking at it.

So I was thinking, why is there no formatting rules? Like PSR for PHP.

Comment: What I see most is that newbies have a hard time using a *Markdown code block* to make their code appear properly on the website. We do have a "rule" there insofar as people *should properly use code blocks.* But that is not what you're asking about, or is it? If you want people to format code according to whatever the accepted practice is in their respective language… well, newbies often have a hard enough time writing any sort of code. The *formatting* is probably something they're only vaguely aware of to begin with…

Comment: Maybe it wouldn't hurt to put a notice when someone posts some badly formatted code (e.g. indented so much that most of it is off the screen) that indenting properly helps get answers quicker. And in HTML snippets, there is a Tidy button. People are free to ignore it, naturally, but it could be made more visible, more inviting.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you @MrLister. That's the least we could do I think and in my opinion the code format is one of the reasons why questions are not getting as mush answers as they could.

Answer (score 10):

The only real "rule" for code is readability.  If the code is not readable, you are empowered to fix that by making the code more readable.

There *are* times when this isn't desirable, such as enforcing your own style standard on someone else's code could mask actual issues (e.g. having your formatter insert braces on your behalf could actually mask the problem the OP was asking about).